# Display in the Template using @Input Decorator in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have `@Input() users` that contains the array of user objects from the parent component. It displays the user's name in the normal table.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now I am using `Angular Material` and would like to implement the table provided by Angular material. For this table, I need the data in the component but I cannot access the data in the child component in `ngOnInit` but can access only access on `ngOnChanges`. Since I can only display the data on the template and not able to manipulate the data on the component, it becomes difficult for me to use the Angular Materail table.

Does somebody have any idea how can I deal with this.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was quite easy..
Getting the value on `ngOnChanges` worked for me.

```
@Input() users;

dataSource;

ngOnChanges() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.users);
}
```